# Nginx Reverse proxy security Issue by Releasing port in AWS security Group

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, reverse-proxy

In AWS EC2 instance am running my application on port 5000. I want to access this application from internet without releasing the port 5000 to public.

step 1)

I have setup nginx as Reverse proxy for my application server running on port 5000

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name inzack.com www.inzack.com;

   location / {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
     return 301 https://$host$uri;
     }

  }

   server {

    listen 443;
    server_name inzack.com www.inzack.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate  /home/ubuntu/certificates/inzack.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /home/ubuntu/certificates/inzack.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

   location / {

                   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;                     
    }

   }
```

step 2) In AWS instance, i have to release the incoming port 5000 in Security Groups, otherwise am unable to access the appliction from internet.

pls suggest without opening the application server port(5000) how can i access it from internet

Thanks

Comment: The website `inzack` seems to work. Can you clarify what exactly is the issue?

Comment: The website is working but the port 5000 is open to all. In AWS Security Groups we enabled incoming connections to all. If i close the port i cannot access the application.

Comment: Just for the clarity, you can screenshot your present SG rules?

Comment: Pls find the screenshot of SG rules https://ibb.co/DzRzFmB